# What's the nature of Monte Carlo noise?

Tags: raytracing, rendering, monte-carlo, noise

Monte Carlo rendering is just a process of sampling and reconstruction to evaluate the rendering equation.

Why is it called noise rather than error?

Comment: I think it's because if you look at just the error it looks like noise, whereas error could be just a positive bias for instance.